# C# extract data from csv

Tags: c#, csv

I have a CSV file like this:

```cs
field1,field2,field3,field4,...,fieldN
1,2,3,,...,N
```

and I want to extract exactly the 14th record of the second row.
I've tried this code:

```
string nomeFile = "externalSourceMsg " + this.DataSource.CodSorgEst + this.DataSource.CodIdSorgEst + ".csv";
string content = "Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4,Field5,Field6,Field7" + Environment.NewLine;
content += externalMessage.ToString();
content = content.Replace(',', ';');

int i = 0;
while (content){
    int field;
    if(i++ == 13)
        field = content+i;
}
```

but it doesn't work. What did I do wrong?

Comment: What do you expect will happen? that looks like an endless loop as `content` will always be a valid string.

Comment: Does that even compile? You're assigning a string (`content+i`) to an int (`field`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split the string and you can access fields by indexes.

```
 string nomeFile = "externalSourceMsg " + this.DataSource.CodSorgEst + this.DataSource.CodIdSorgEst + ".csv";
 string content = "Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4,Field5,Field6,Field7" + Environment.NewLine;
 content += externalMessage.ToString();
 content = content.Replace(',', ';');

 // Split the string by your separator -> you will get an array filled with fields
 string[] contentArr = content.Split(';');
 // Access any field you'd like by indexes 
 var The14thField = contentArr[13];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
// Read all lines and get the second (this can be done 
// in more optimal way, just by reading two first lines)
var secondLine = File.ReadLines("Path")[1];
// Split byb comma and get 14th item in returned array
var entry = secondLine.Split(",")[13];
```